# simulating with php-json API, an xml-like json structure

Tags: php, xml, json

Good day everyone. I am trying to simulate (with php), an xml-like structure for json
as follows:

```html
{
    "Articles": [
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 111,
                "title": Origin of man",
                "author": "Man and Woman",
                "pubDate": "21st Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Both Idiots"
            }
        },
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 222,
                "title": "Origin of Animals",
                "author": "Animal and Man",
                "pubDate": "22nd Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Yet another Idiots"
            }
        },
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 333,
                "title": "Origin of Politicians",
                "author": "Politicians and Man",
                "pubDate": "23rd Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Inexplicable Idiots"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, "Articles" is the root node equvalence of json (as in xml)
and "Article" is the child nodes, with different IDs.
my question is, how can i programatically add a sub-child to 
(or sub-record) to Article identified by 222, such that the 
entires structure becomes something like this:

```html
{
    "Articles": [
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 111,
                "title": Origin of man",
                "author": "Man and Woman",
                "pubDate": "21st Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Both Idiot"
            }
        },
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 222,
                "title": "Origin of Animals":
                "SUB-TITLES": 
                           { 
                             "SUB_TITLE_1": "Just kidding",
                             "SUB_TITLE_2": "Still Kiddng",
                             "SUB_TITLE_3": "Dont be offended"
                           }     
                "author": "Animal and Man",
                "pubDate": "22nd Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Yet another Idiots"
            }
        },
        {
            "Article": {
                "ID": 333,
                "title": "Origin of Politicians",
                "author": "Politicians and Man",
                "pubDate": "23rd Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Inexplicable Idiots"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my attempt, but doesnt seem good enough
though everything worked smoothly witout error,
but the output is not what i am actually expecting. Here's it:

```html
{ 
   "Articles": [
       {
           "Article":  {
               "ID":111,
               "title":"Origin of man",
               "author":"Man and Woman",
               "pubDate":"21st Feb, 2014",
               "summary":"Both Idiot"
           }
       },

       {
           "Article":  {
               "ID":222,
               "title":"Origin of Animals":
                       //i expected to have SUB-TITLES record here, but didnt
               "author":"Osagie Odigie",
               "pubDate":"22nd Feb, 2014",
               "summary":"Yet another Idiots"
            }
       },

       {
            "Article": {
                "ID":333,
                "title": "Origin of Politicians",
                "author": "Politicians and Man",
                "pubDate": "23rd Feb, 2014", 
                "summary": "Inexplicable Idiots"
            }
       }
    ], 
    //Now, here's where SUB-TITLES record showed up
    "0":{ "SUB-TITLES": [
             {"SUB_TITLE_1": "Just kidding"},
             {"SUB_TITLE_2": "Still Kiddng"},
             {"SUB_TITLE_3": "Dont be offended"}
           ]
         }
}
```

As it is, i cant tell what exactly am doing wrong and i 
cant also tell the source of that zero preceeding 
the opening brace before "SUB-TITLES":, neither can i tell
from were the brace is coming. any guidiance or a code snipette
on how to do it well will be highly appreciated. thanks 
to my helper in anticipation.

```html
Sure ! i anticipate writing it to my file for permanent
storage if all goes fine. for now, i'm just displaying it on my browser
using: 

 echo json_encode($data);

Here's an extract of the code:

 function JSONAddRecordToChild(array $Record, $ChildID){
        
        
        $file = file_get_contents("File.json", true);
        $data = json_decode($file, true);                   //get json by assoc array
        unset($file);                                    //prevent memory leaks for large json 
        
        //only when ID does not exist, write record to json 
        $node = $this->searchJSON($data["Articles"], $ChildID);         //costumized searchJSON methode that returns a matching node
        if($node != null){
            
            $node = array("SUB-TITLES" => array()); 
            
            foreach ($Record as $key => $value){ 
                $node["SUB-TITLES"][] = array($key => $value);
            }
            
            foreach ($data as $child){
                foreach ($child as $son){ 
                    if($son["Article"]['ID'] == $ChildID){ 
                        $data[] = $node;
                    }  
                }
            } 

           echo json_encode($data).;  

           //to be written permanently to file as mentioned
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code.  It's impossible to tell without knowing what you're actually doing vs. a bunch of big JSON dumps.

Comment: You have to post code for this or it will be closed. You are using [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to make your JSON right?

Comment: @Brian, i made an update of the code snippet (see main post again) for ur perusal. pls get in touch ASAP ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is inside your last `foreach` loop.  You're checking to see if the inner element `$son` matches the desired ID, but then you're setting the sub-titles on the root-level `$data`

TL;DR Change

```
if($son["Article"]['ID'] == $ChildID){ 
    $data[] = $node;
}
```

to

```
if($son["Article"]['ID'] == $ChildID){ 
    $son["Article"][] = $node;
}
```

Comment: A million thanks Brian. i seem to be getting it
rightly. but not with the removal of the trailing
array indices. the 0, 1, 2... ith are still showing
in the browser output. as in:

"0": { "SUB-TITLES": [
             {"SUB_TITLE_1": "Just kidding"},
             {"SUB_TITLE_2": "Still Kiddng"},
             {"SUB_TITLE_3": "Dont be offended"}
           ]
     }

"1": {}
"nth": {}..

is there anything that can be done to get rid of this
for ease of readability in future

once again, thanks !